# for...of loop weird behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been playing around with dynamic assignment of routes in express and stumbled into unexpected behavior from for ... of loop.

My idea was simple:

1. Create simple array

   `const roomsArray = ["Algebra", "Backend", "Frontend"];`
2. loop through that array and create a route for each item in array, so I tried with for ... of loop

   ````
    router.get(`/room/${i}`, isUser, (req, res) => {
      res.render("index/room", { path: "index/room", name: i });
    })
   } ```
   ````

And the result was more than unexpected(to me at least). Each route was created as expected, but whichever route I would test, value of `i` assigned to `name` was always value of last item in array.

Switching over to for loop or forEach solves the issue and everything behaves as expected, however I would like to know **why does this behavior occur using for ... of statement?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have shown the loop perhaps. Based on the description you probably have `var`:

```js
for(var x of [1,2,3])
  setTimeout(()=>console.log(x),0);
```

and could just have `let` instead for a fix:

```js
for(let x of [1,2,3])
  setTimeout(()=>console.log(x),0);
```

`let` is scoped at block level, so each callback sees a separate variable. `var` is scoped at function-level (or here, globally), so each callbacks see the same variable with the last value inside.

Comment: My apologies, I failed to notice that I copied the code snippet incorrectly. Your answer answers it all.